# phpmyadmin: The json extension is missing

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin

## What I have done

I have set up a LAMP webserver using these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Then I installed `phpmyadmin` with:

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

---

## The problem

The problem is that when I go to http://localhost/phpmyadmin/,
I get this:

> **phpMyAdmin - Error**
> The json extension is missing. Please check your
>   PHP configuration.

---

## What I've tried

I've tried:

- https://superuser.com/questions/639945/how-to-fix-the-phpmyadmin-error-json-extension-is-missing
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27818040/phpmyadmin-error-the-json-extension-is-missing
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WoLKOBmikXo

## System info

- Clean install of Ubuntu 14.04 x64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.

I had replaced the default `php.ini` file with one from a different server, and that must have messed it up.

I reinstalled LAMP & phpmyadmin, this time leaving `php.ini` alone, and it worked just fine.